# How do I get multiple value input to json object with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, stringify

I have input tag html like this :

```
<form id="info">
    <input id="A" name="A" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="A">
    <input id="A1" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val">
    <input id="A2" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val">
    <input id="B" name="B" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="B">
    <input id="B1" name="B1" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B1">
    <input id="B2" name="B2" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B2">
<form>
```

I pass value in jquery like this :

```
function writeJSONfile() {
    var obj = {};
    $("form#info :input").each(function(){
        obj[this.id] = $(this).val();
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    alert("check"+json);
}
```

Result :

```
{"A":"A","A1":"a1val","A2":"a2val","B":"B","B1":"b1val","B2":"b2val"}
```

But My Expect Result is :

```
{"A":{"A1":"a1val","A2":"a2val"},"B":{"B1":"b1val","B2":"b2val"}}
```

You can read JSON with json editor online.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing occurs, because you haven't written code that distinguishes values like `'A'`, `'B'` from `'A1'`, `'B1'` etc. All you need, in order to make the code work is:

- a variable that references the object which the property should be added to &
- a simple `if` check that will direct the flow accordingly.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function writeJSONfile() {
  var
    /* Create an object. */
    obj = {},
    
    /* Create a variable that references the current object (default → obj). */
    ref = obj;
    
  /* Iterate over every input. */
  $("form#info :input").each(function() {
    /* Cache the id of the input. */
    var id = this.id;
    
    /* Check whether the nodetype attribute is set to 'parent'. */
    if (this.getAttribute("nodetype") == "parent") {
      /* Set a new object to the property and set ref to refer to it. */
      ref = obj[id] = {};
    }
    else {
      /* Set the value of the input to the referred object. */
      ref[id] = $(this).val();
    }
  });
  
  /* Stringify the object and return it. */
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

/* Create and log the result. */
console.log(writeJSONfile());
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="info">
  <input id="A" name="A" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="A"/>
  <input id="A1" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val"/>
  <input id="A2" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val"/>
  <input id="B" name="B" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="B"/>
  <input id="B1" name="B1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="b1val"/>
  <input id="B2" name="B2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="b2val"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what if  id='A' change to id='12'

Comment: Thx Angel Politis. But In your case you check length of 'id' right. In my case cannot check length of 'id' but this can help me now Thank you so much. I will get another attribute to check parent and child.

Comment: The OP can adjust the checking condition to fit their exact case @yajiv. My answer serves as guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes on the managment of `classes` and `ids`. A quick an easy function to solve your problem.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
function writeJSONfile() {
  var obj = {};

  $(".main").each(function() {
    var mainId = this.id;
    obj[this.id] = {};
    $("input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass(mainId)) {
        obj[mainId][this.id] = $(this).val();;
      }
    })
  });
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  alert("check" + json);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="info">
  <input id="A" class="main" name="A" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="A">
  <input id="A1" class="A" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val">
  <input id="A2" class="A" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val">
  <input id="B" class="main" name="B" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="B">
  <input id="B1" class="B" name="B1" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B1">
  <input id="B2" class="B" name="B2" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B2">
  <form>
    <button onclick="writeJSONfile()">Run</button>
```

Comment: Thx @Gerardo BLANCO. Your Result can use also.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
   function writeNodeJSON() {
       var obj = {};
       var ref = obj;
       $("form#info :input").each(function () {
           var id = this.id;
           if ($(this).attr("nodetype")==="parent") {
               obj[id] = {};
               ref = obj[id];
           } else
               ref[id] = $(this).val();
       });
       console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    //    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    //    return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }}
```

I check by attribute name "nodetype"

Comment: Thanks @Angel Politis for helping me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @C.Tin! Checking the `nodetype` attribute is a nice idea *(I edited my answer to include it, since it's better than checking the `length`)*, but be sure to correct your `HTML`, because some `input` elements in the code you provided have `nodetye` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the input with `nodetype` `parent` and update the `obj` object with its `id` as key and `{}` as value. Then iterate through all input element with `nodetype` as `child` and add all the id as key and value as input box value in the object.

```js
function writeJSONfile() {
  var obj = {};
  $('form#info :input[nodetype=parent]').each(function(){
    obj[this.id] = {};
  })
  $("form#info :input[nodetype=child]").each(function(){
    if(!(this.id[0] in obj))
      obj[this.id[0]] = {};
    obj[this.id[0]][this.id] = $(this).val();
  });
  var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(json);
}
writeJSONfile();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="info">
  <input id="A" name="A" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="A">
  <input id="A1" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val">
  <input id="A2" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val">
  <input id="B" name="B" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="B">
  <input id="B1" name="B1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="B1">
  <input id="B2" name="B2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="B2">
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function writeJSONfile() {
  var obj = {};
  $(".main").each(function() {
    var mainId = this.id;
    obj[mainId] = {};
    $("."+mainId).each(function() {
      obj[mainId][this.id] = $(this).val();      
    })
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="info">
  <input id="A" class="main" name="A" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="A">
  <input id="A1" class="A" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val">
  <input id="A2" class="A" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val">
  <input id="B" class="main" name="B" type="hidden" nodetye="parent" value="B">
  <input id="B1" class="B" name="B1" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B1">
  <input id="B2" class="B" name="B2" type="text" nodetye="child" value="B2">
  <form>
    <input type="button" onclick="writeJSONfile()" value="Run">
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this may works:

```js
function writeJSONfile() {
  debugger;
    var obj = {};
    var children = {};
    $("form#info :input").each(function(){
      var parent = this;
      if(parent.getAttribute("nodetype")=="parent"){
         obj[parent.id] = {};
          var nexts = $(parent).nextAll();
          for(let i=0;i<nexts.length;i++){
           if(nexts[i].getAttribute("nodetype")!="child"){
             break;
            }else{
             obj[parent.id][nexts[i].id] = $(nexts[i]).val();
            }
          }
        }
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    alert("check"+json);
}
writeJSONfile();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="info">
      <input id="A" name="A" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="A">
      <input id="A1" name="A1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a1val">
      <input id="A2" name="A2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="a2val">
      <input id="B" name="B" type="hidden" nodetype="parent" value="B">
      <input id="B1" name="B1" type="text" nodetype="child" value="B1">
      <input id="B2" name="B2" type="text" nodetype="child" value="B2">
    <form>
```